# Check if all elements of a subarray of an array doesn't exist in the rest of the array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Let's say we have an array `a` = { ... } and we should answer some queries, each query consist of 2 indices `l` and `r` , the answer of the each query is `YES` or `NO` :

Yes : if all the elements of the subarray [l,r] doesn't exist in the rest of the array ( segment [1,l-1] and segment [r+1,n] ).

No : otherwise

The best thing I could come with is o(n^3) solution : iterating each segment (i,j) which take O(n^2) and then for each segment check all elements of that segment so it's O(n^3) overall.

I need at least O(n^2) solution or some hint, thanks.

ex : a = [4, 4, 2, 5, 2, 3]
queries :

1 2 -> YES

3 5 -> YES

2 3 -> NO

4 6 -> NO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Preprocessing:** Loop over the array and create a hashmap `counts` of each element to the count of how often it appears in the array.

**For each query:** Loop over the subarray and create a hashmap `queryCounts` to store the count of each element. Look up each element of `queryCounts` in `counts` and compare the counts - return "yes" if all the counts match, "no" otherwise.

**Running time:** Expected **O(n) preprocessing and O(n) per query**.

**Pseudo-code:**

(Assume elements that don't exist in the map will be initialised to 0 when you try to access them, similar to C++'s `std::map`)

Preprocessing:

```java
array[n] // the input array

Map<int -> int> counts
for i = 1 to n
   counts[array[i]]++
```

For a query `i j`:

```java
Map<int -> int> queryCounts
for x = i to j
   queryCounts[array[x]]++
for each key y in queryCounts
   if queryCounts[y] != counts[y]
      return "no"
return "yes"
```

**Example:**

Array: `[4, 4, 2, 5, 2, 3]`

The hashmap will be:

```java
2 -> 2
3 -> 1
4 -> 2
5 -> 1
```

If have a query `3 4` (1-based) over the subarray [2, 5], we'll get:

```java
2 -> 1
5 -> 1
```

We compare this with the first hashmap and see that the counts for `2` don't match, so we return "no".

---

---

**Alternative approach:**

You can also loop over all subarrays during preprocessing and store whether you'll return "yes" or "no" to get **O(n<sup>2</sup>) preprocessing and O(1) per query**.

Note that the hashmap for `[i,j]` can be obtained from `[i,j-1]`'s hashmap by adding 1 to the count of `array[j]`, thus we only need to do O(1) work per subarray during preprocessing if we keep track of the number of counts which are wrong and only check how changing `array[j]`'s count will change this number.

**Pseudo-code:**

Preprocessing:

```java
array[n] // the input array

Map<(int, int) -> String> queryResults
for i = 1 to n
   Map<int -> int> queryCounts // clear on every i iteration
   countsWrong = 0
   for j = i to n
      if queryCounts[array[j]] == counts[array[j]]
         countsWrong++ // the counts match, the below operation will make it not match
      queryCounts[array[j]]++
      if queryCounts[array[j]] == counts[array[j]]
         countsWrong--
      if countsWrong == 0
         queryResults[i,j] = "yes"
      else
         queryResults[i,j] = "no"
```

For a query `i j`:

```java
return queryResults[i,j]
```

**Example:**

Array: `[4, 4, 2]`

The hashmap will be:

```java
2 -> 1
4 -> 2
```

We start with `i=1, j=1`:

```java
4 -> 1
countsWrong = 1 // since 4's count is wrong (not 2)
queryResults[1,1] = "no"
```

For `i=1, j=2`, we add 1 to 4's count:

```java
4 -> 2
countsWrong = 0 // 4's count is now right
queryResults[1,2] = "yes"
```

For `i=1, j=3`, we add 1 to 2's count:

```java
4 -> 2
2 -> 1
countsWrong = 1 // 2's count is right
queryResults[1,3] = "yes"
```

For `i=2, j=2`, we reset the map and 1 to 4's count:

```java
4 -> 1
countsWrong = 1 // 4's count is wrong (not 2)
queryResults[2,2] = "no"
```

For `i=2, j=3`, we add 1 to 2's count:

```java
4 -> 1
2 -> 1
countsWrong = 1 // 2's count is right, 4's is wrong (not 2)
queryResults[2,3] = "no"
```

For `i=3, j=3`, we reset the map and 1 to 2's count:

```java
2 -> 1
countsWrong = 0 // 2's count is right
queryResults[1,2] = "yes"
```

Comment: Thank's for you reply, but I was looking for an O(1) per query because this problem is a part of a bigger problem where the queries are inside an O(n^2) loops, so it will be O(n^3) overall, what I need is some processing , that can make queries executed in O(1), sorry not to mention that.

Comment: @AbdenaceurLichiheb I edited my answer and added an O(1) per query approach. I can add an example or some pseudo-code if it's not clear.

Comment: it will be better if you provide some code, I'm having a hard time understanding your solution :p

Comment: also what do you mean by array[j]? is it the hashmap that holds the count of element ?

Comment: @AbdenaceurLichiheb Updated. `array[j]` is the `j`'s element of the input array.

Comment: Thanks for you effort.